# how to interpolate data value for a given set of coordinates from the original coordinates in python

Tags: python, 3d, interpolation

I have a 3D data matrix `A` and their corresponding coordinates `(x,y,z)` to each data point. I want to get the interpolated data values for a different set of coordinates `(x', y', z')` in python.

I'm trying to implement it with `scipy.interpolate.griddata` or `RegularGridInterpolator`.

My difficulties are:
1) my `z'` in the new coordinates are not always the same as the `z` in original coordinates. 
`scipy.interpolate.griddata` seems need a 2D input `xi`;

2) I have some difficulties to map the data values to its original coordinates to use `RegularGridInterpolator`, because my data value in `A` is not a well-defined math function of the coordinates `(x,y,z)`.

Could anyone give me some guidance on this? Thank you very much!

Comment: Can you share what you've tried and where you are getting stuck? Please try to provide a [mcve].

Comment: If I have not misunderstood the question, the answer is as simple as multiplying the sample location by the inverse of the transformation matrix from `(x, y, z)` to `(x', y', z')`, to obtain the corresponding sample point in the original coordinate system, then use whatever interpolation functionality from there.